# Neo4JClient: How can I find a list of relationships (of any type) for a given node?

Tags: c#, neo4j, neo4jclient

I know how to get the related nodes, and to specify the relationships to find those nodes, but there doesn't seem to be any mechanism to find the relationships themselves?

Looking through the source code for Neo4JClient you can find the type "Relationship" but it's only used when creating Relationships, not in retrieving them.

When retrieving, you can get a "RelationshipInstance", but it consists of a RelationshipReference and two NodeReferences..  None of which have any data associated with them besides the unique integer ID associated with each.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want access to data stored on relationships. We refer to these as "payloads".

You can query them like so:

```
client
    .RootNode
    .OutE<FooPayload>()
    .Select(p =>
    {
        p.Reference.Id,         // Relationship ID
        p.StartNodeReference,   // Outbound vertex
        p.EndNodeReference,     // Inbound vertex
        p.Data,                 // Payload as FooPayload
        p.Data.Bar              // A property in the payload
    });
```

More likely, you'd want to use an overload of OutE that filters the relationships by type, like:

```
client
    .RootNode
    .OutE<FooPayload>("HAS_FOO")
```

If you use the overload of OutE without the generic type parameter, you will get the references but no payload data (because we don't know what to deserialize the data into).

HTH.

-- Tatham

Comment: How do I get the TypeKey value?   I want to get ALL relationships for this Node, with their typeKey values.   Ideally what I'd like to do is to be able to intelligently update the relationships.   I can add relationships within a single .Create() call, but I can't update relationships, except individually.

Comment: I also tried to use OutE<Relationship> or OutE<TenantBelongsToRoot> which derives from the various IRelationship interfaces or OutE<IRelationshipAllowingParticipantNode<RootNode>> but all failed to compile because they don't implement a public parameterless constructor.

Comment: Hm... Looking more closely at Relationship<TData> Do I need to put the TypeKey value as a payload "TData" to be able to deserialize it in OutE<>?

Comment: Oh. You want all relationships, of all types, in a single call, with data, which you can then update? How could we possibly deserialize that? There's a different model type for each relationship with data. It's like saying you want to retrieve every node in the system in one hit ... what type would we put them in other than a dumb dictionary?

Comment: I was thinking an IEnumerable<Relationship> would work well, but I think I can work with what's there now, if I use the payload.

Comment: Build 1.0.0.350 is on its way to NuGet right now and it adds support for: client.RootNode.OutE().Select(p => p.TypeKey);